# probability of n 1.5 dimension uniform random points have k in convex position?

Tags: probability, convex-geometry, discrete-geometry

I can randomly realize a sequence $S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_n$ of $n$ samples from a uniform random distribution $U(0, 1)$.

Using the sequence as a $x$ axis, and assign even space $a$, where $a \in\mathbb{R}^+$ between them in the $y$ axis, we can obtain a planar set of points.

The coordinate of "1.5" dimension planar point sequence would be  $P = (S_1, 0), (S_2, a), \cdots, (S_i, a*i), \cdots(S_n, a*n)$.

My interest is how to compute the probability of having $k$ point in convex position?

And what is the expected number of points that is in convex position?

Comment: Really interesting question! By convex, do you mean the extremal points of the convex hull of $P$ are equal to $P$? Also, what do you mean by $1.5$-dimensional?

Comment: > By convex, do you mean the extremal points of the convex hull of  are equal to ?  yes!, and 1.5 -dimensional is just a catchy name, it's meant for the y-axis is not random.

Comment: The following approach is pretty non-mathy, but if I had to solve this problem I'd probably start with a bunch of numerical simulations to get an idea if the probability changes as a function of $n$. Since you're in $2$D, you can do [Graham scans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) pretty efficiently

Comment: right, yeah i can simulate for sure, and i might just do that, but overall I'm interested in how analytically people would approach this type of question, cz clearly I'll make changes to the "even" space part of y axis into something more random :)